# Symplectic orbifolds

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, orbifolds

I will start by saying that I am not a symplectic topology. However, in my research I now have on my hands a symplectic 4-orbifold, which I would like to understand better. Certain results for symplectic manifolds (e.g. Weinstein’s Lagrangian neighborhood theorem), if true in this more general setting, would help immensely.

Therefore, I would like to know if the theory of symplectic orbifolds has been developed at all, and if so, where can I read about it.

Again, I am mostly interested in 4-orbifolds, so even results in this dimension would help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is a nice new research. I have started to study on it. In fact symplectic orbifold is in the category of "symplectic hopfoid". such category provide a characterization
of symplectic double groupoids and there is a conjecture that symplectic orbifold can be constructed by such structures.

Comment: continue-----> Geometric quantization of such symplectic orbifolds and moduli space of them has not been studied yet.

Comment: As an example : Take oriented Seifert $S^1$-orbibundle over a $\mathbb CP^1$ orbifold  which could be seen as  singular Hamiltonian
structure of fibration, which the Reeb orbit space
is a symplectic orbifold . In fact Symplectic orbifold gives a connection between Symplectic Field theory and ancient symplectic geometry

Comment: I give another natural example.  Take $G$ be a compact Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$,
and suppose that $G$ acts on a symplectic manifold $X$ by symplectomorphisms. Take the moment map $\mu:X\to \mathfrak g^*$, then $\mu^{-1}(\alpha)/G$,  If $\alpha$ is a regular central value of $\mu$,then $\mu^{-1}(\alpha)/G$, is a symplectic orbifold. Symplectic orbifold is study of Morse theory also